# Excel payment of installmenst deducting debit balance

Tags: excel, payment

I have an Excel sheet that we manually segregates the total amount paid in there installments.

Like the example below:

| Customer no | Installment no | Installment Value | Total Paid | Inst Value Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XC005 | 1 | 350.00 | 1000.00 |  |
| XC005 | 2 | 350.00 | 0.00 |  |
| XC005 | 3 | 350.00 | 0.00 |  |
| XC018 | 1 | 25.00 | 36.00 |  |
| XC018 | 2 | 25.00 |  |  |

Column E is where we segregate the amount.

Tried using IF formula deducting the amount that remains of the other installments, but the issue is identifying the change of customers.

Which formula to use to solve this issue?

Manually doing will look like this:

| Customer no | Installment no | Installment Value | Total Paid | Inst Value Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XC005 | 1 | 350.00 | 1000.00 | 350.00 |
| XC005 | 2 | 350.00 | 0.00 | 350.00 |
| XC005 | 3 | 350.00 | 0.00 | 300.00 |
| XC018 | 1 | 25.00 | 36.00 |  |
| XC018 | 2 | 25.00 |  |  |

For the customer XC018 we will split his total amount (36.00) in this 2 installments were E5 will be 25.00 and E6 will be 11.00 that the left value after deducting the first inst.

Comment: It is not clear what you are requesting. Are you trying to sum the values of Column `Installment Value`?

Comment: Are looking for `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2)`?

Comment: Hey Harun, i think sumifs will not work on this case, but will try using your ans Shane suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `LET()` to produce the `SUMIFS()` and a `IF()` to test if the installment is complete and when it is not use `MOD()`. I will use "tp" to represent "Total Paid".

documentation on [LET()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999). The formula becomes:

```
=LET(tp,SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A3),IF(tp/C3>B3,C3,MOD(tp,C3)))
```

copy and past the above in cell C3 then copy and past to all needed cells from there.

If you have trouble with LET(). Then use the below.

```
=IF(SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A3)/C3>B3,C3,MOD(SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A3),C3))
```

Comment: Hey Shane, thanks for the initial help.
Let me try to explain this better (Not english native and i'm little bit rusty at writing)...

So, manually what we do is, we check if the total amount is greater than the first installment not paid. If higher we input the installment value at the collumn E. in the first case $350.00. to the next installment we now have 650.00 total paid left after deducting the first one. 650.00 greater than 350.00 of the 2nd Inst so we input $350.00. After deducting we have $300.00 for the last inst. The 3rd inst value is 350.00 that is greater than tha amount left

Comment: i will demonstrate what looks like at the question

Comment: @JoãoScotelaro, I have changed the answer based on the question and comments.

Comment: Hey Shane, thanks for the help, will try "LET" formula today, and be back bring the results.